# How to use ISO7816 select command with DESfire Ev1 card?

Tags: nfc, smartcard, mifare

I have a DESfire Ev1 version 1.3 card and I'm trying to select a file using ISO7816 apdu style.

I have one file, with aid `A0 A1 A2` and I can select it using both native or wrapped mode:

Native:

```
-> 5A A0 A1 A2
<- 00
```

Wrapped:

```
-> 90 5A 00 00 03 A0 A1 A2 00
<- 91 00
```

However, if I try to select it using ISO7816 style, I always get a file not found error:

ISO7816:

```
-> 00 A4 04 00 03 A0 A1 A2 00
-> 6A 82
```

When using ISO apdu, is the AID in a different format? How can I select this AID using it?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Nice first question; you described your problem succinctly, added the expected result, provided the actual result, and narrowed it down to only the information that reproduces the issue.

Comment: Ah, thanks :) I think it's the effect of the years of lurking around :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<strike>From the docs:</strike>

> This APDU selects an ISO Application by it’s ISO Application
>   Identifier (AID). The ISO AID of DESFire is ”0xD2 76 00 00 85 01 00”.
>   The full ISO AID has to be transmitted, partial selection is NOT
>   supported. Other ISO AIDs are not supported by DESFire

This appears to contradict the fact that you have an AID `0xA0 0xA1 0xA2`.

Seems like you need to be sending:

```
[CLA] [INS] [P1] [P2] [Len(AID)] [AID]
```

Thus:

0x00 0xA4 0x04 0x00 0x07 0xD2 0x76 0x00 0x00 0x85 0x01 0x00

** EDIT **

Try `ISO SELECT DIRECTORY` instead:

> This APDU selects a DESFire Application by it’s three byte DESFire
>   Application Identifier (DESFire AID).   ...
>
> The functionality of the ISO SELECT DIRECTORY Command is compatible
>   with the native DESFire “Select Application” command.

So:

```
0x00 0xA4 0x04 0x00 0x03 0xA0 0xA1 0xA2
```

(this was on the following page, and probably what you wanted in the first place.)

I think this is identical to what you had, minus the `NUL` at the end.

Comment: Ok, now I'm confused. I've used `0xA0 A1 A2` because inside DESfire the files must have three byte long IDs. So `CA A0 A1 A2 0F 01` created this application and I can select using `5A A0 A1 A2`. This AID refers to the card itself, then? (And it would automagically select the master file?)

Comment: It's contradictory to me as well; the manual effectively says that you must hardcode that ID (page 72 of the product spec.), and that the ID is 7 bytes. It's almost as if you cannot select individual files in the ISO 7816 mode.

Comment: If I can't select individual files than it still possible to write data in the master file? I don't have my reader with me at the moment, but I'll see what I can do when I have it (tomorrow).

Comment: Take a look at my edit; I think you just need to get rid of the `NUL` at the end of your attempt.

Comment: I'll try and post the results tomorrow! Thanks!

Comment: Good luck; if I'm wrong, and this isn't helpful, let me know and I'll delete it.

Comment: So, if I use `00 a4 04 00 07 d2 76 00 00 85 01 00` it works (response `90 00`) but if I use `00 a4 04 00 03 a0 a1 a2` it doesn't. Now I have to figure out how to use it properly.